# Нужно сделать проверку на одинаковые числа в цикле

Tags: циклы

$arr -массив.$num = 10. Нужно сделать проверку, если в массиве есть сумма которая есть в переменной $num  вывести 1. Что делаю не так

```
function t10($num,$arr)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i <= count($arr); $i++){
        if($num === $arr[$i]){
            return 1;
        } 
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: num  --- sum ???

Comment: Точно, спасибо)) Подправил но почему то 0 все равно, хотя число есть в массиве.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несколько ошибок:

1. не `$sum`, а `$num`
2. если соблюдается какое-либо из условий, то сразу происходит выход из функции. Соответственно, если первое значение не совпадает с условием, то сразу происходит return 0. Цикл дальше не выполняется, т.к. из функции уже вернули значение и вышли из неё

Проблема решается чуть по-другому:

- запускается цикл
- если значение совпадает, то делаем `return true;` (1)
- а **вне цикла** ставится `return false;` (0) . Т.к. если весь цикл отработал, значит ничего не нашлось.

Comment: Спасибо большое, попробую